# Get Windows 10 universal app installation package - for individual installation

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

Alright, I'm currently trying to figure out, how can I get my Windows 10 universal app to package, so I could send it to another person and he could use that program.

I managed to create some kind of package, but it still seems to be for Windows Store..

Couldn't find a good answer from Google as well, mostly still about how to get that app to store -.-'

What I mean is for example, if I do a Console app, then I can get that .exe file and execute that in any computer. Does Win 10 Universal App even support this kind of feature?

Currently getting this kind of error, if trying to execute that from bin folder:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [sideload your app package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454036.aspx#InstallRemote)

Comment: This seems to be one way indeed, just not very user friendly tho.

Comment: I agree..but I think is the only way to ship the app